# geth account new could not decrypt key with given passphrase

Tags: blockchain, geth

I want to synchronize with the network test network. I create a new user with the following command:

**sudo geth --datadir/data/ethereum/test --keystore /data/ethereum/test/keystore account new**

Next, I run:

**sudo geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --datadir /data/ethereum/test --keystore /data/ethereum/test/keystore --maxpeers 20 --cache=1024 --rpc --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --rpcport=8545 --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*" console**

An error occurs:

**WARN [12-06 | 11: 29: 30.933] Failed account unlock attempt address = 0x06C55Ac0d9C14348D5b63FC693e134889340ecBa err = "cannot decrypt key with given passphrase".**

I enter the password 100% correct.
Ports are open

**tcp: 80, 8080, 443, 30000 - 30999, 8545**.

**udp: 30000 - 30999.**

I connect to the server using **PuTTY**. Server: **ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64**. If you delete all accounts and create anew, this error will still occur. If the network is synchronized and I create a new account, it is still an error.

Comment: I use geth version 1.8.19

Comment: What the hell it doesn't work!?

Comment: And yes i am use --unlock and enter pass. geth does not work long and gives the same error.

Comment: Please format your question properly. It is very hard to read/understand.

Comment: Corrected. I hope now is clear.